# The data type, or dtype, of each column is properly set? well i understand the question but i have few doubts

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv('nat2018.csv',sep=';')
df = df.rename({'sexe': 'gender', 'preusuel': 'name','annais':'year','nombre':'births'}, axis=1)
df = df.reindex(columns=['year','name','gender','births'])
df['gender']=df['gender'].map({1:'M',2:'F'})
df = df[df['name'].ne('A') & df['year'].ne('XXXX')]
df['name']=df.name.str.lower()
df['name']=df.name.str.capitalize()
df = df.sort_values(by= ['year','gender','births'],ascending=False)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

friends, actually I am doing my python assignment and I performed a few manipulations according to requirement of my assignment. Now one of my requirements is: The data type, or dtype, of each column, is properly set?
so i tested the data type of columns with df.dtyes and i got output as
year : object , name : object , gender : object , births : int64

My questions are as follows :

1) Should I change the data type of year column to int64 and change name & gender to str? and how can I do it? I tried doing it by df.astype({'year': 'int64'}).dtypes but after running it successfully when I tested it again by using df.dtypes nothing changed year was still object.

2) when I am running the entire manipulation within a function: let's say

```
def exercise_01():

df = pd.read_csv('nat2018.csv',sep=';')
df = df.rename({'sexe': 'gender', 'preusuel': 'name','annais':'year','nombre':'births'}, axis=1)
df = df.reindex(columns=['year','name','gender','births'])
df['gender']=df['gender'].map({1:'M',2:'F'})
df = df[df['name'].ne('A') & df['year'].ne('XXXX')]
df['name']=df.name.str.lower()
df['name']=df.name.str.capitalize()
df = df.sort_values(by= ['year','gender','births'],ascending=False)
df.reset_index(drop=True)

return df
```

nothing is displayed? I don't know why? should I try returning print (df) in place of df ?

Comment: Please don't share code/data as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900. I think your first question can be easily answered by reading the Pandas docs. As for the second one, I think you just might not understand functions and returning values.

Comment: @AMC well I have an IT background in Oracle..the issue is I am new to python ...but I can understand functions bcoz sometime before I was writing it in Oracle Plsql...but the thing is I did a stupidity i was running the function in the note book without calling it..

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses the `object` dtype for storing strings. So if you have an **object** column, It can be treated as a **string** one.
If you consider that 'birthday' is a column you have to make calculations with you can change the type data to a `numeric`. If you want to change the type of any column. In this case, for example, the 'birthday' you must run:

```
df["birthday"] = df["birthday"].astype("int")
```

The function you are using doesn't need to return the dataframe, because you are modifying it inside of the function and the dataframe scope is global.

Comment: _so if you have an object column, It means that is a string one._ That isn't true, be careful! You can find more information here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes.